# Taxonomy archive page WP_Query does not return get_the_permalink() or get_permalink() value

Tags: taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

In a taxonomy archive page, within the following loop:

```
$type = 'classes';
$page_taxonomy = get_query_var( 'classes_class_type', 'yoga' );
wp_reset_query();

$args=array(
'post_type' => $type,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'classes_class_type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $page_taxonomy,
        ),
    )
);

$query = null;
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Both of the following return desired result:

```
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php
        $class_type = wp_get_post_terms( $query->post->ID, 'classes_class_type' );
        $teacher = get_post_meta($query->post->ID, 'teacher');
```

These work:

```
$post->post_name
$post->post_title
$query->post->ID
$post->ID
```

Post object:

```
$query->post
```

But:

```
get_the_permalink($query->post->ID);
get_permalink($query->post->ID);
get_permalink($query->post);
```

Nothing.

Commenting out the `'post_type'` and `'tax_query'` arguments from the `WP_Query($args)`, `get_permalink` and `get_the_permalink` return URLs.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I had broken the permalink structure for the CPT with the following filter:

```
    function classes_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $permalink, $sample)
        {

        if (strpos($permalink, '%classes_class_type%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

                    // Get post
                    $post = get_post($post_id);
                    if (!$post) return $permalink;

                    // Get taxonomy terms
                    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'classes_class_type');   
                    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
                    else $taxonomy_slug = 'all-class-types';

            return str_replace('%classes_class_type%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);

        }
    add_filter('post_type_link', 'classes_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
```

My understanding of permalink restructuring, largely based on [this tutorial](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks-part-2) is still quite vague.

As far as I can tell, the following code:

```
    $class_type_structure = '/classes/%classes_class_type%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%classes_class_type%", '([^/]+)', "classes_class_type=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('classes_class_type', $class_type_structure, false);
```

registered in the `init` filter (along with register_taxonomy in this case) seems to be all that's necessary:

```
function create_class_type_taxonomies() {
    if (!taxonomy_exists('classes_class_type')) {
        register_taxonomy(
            'classes_class_type',
            'classes',
            array(
                    'labels' => array(
                            'name' => 'Class Type'
                    ),
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'show_tagcloud' => false,
                    'hierarchical' => false,
                    'publicly_queryable' => true,
                    'query_var' => true,
                    'rewrite' => true
                    )
                );
            }
        global $wp_rewrite;

        $class_type_structure = '/class-type/%classes_class_type%';
        $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%classes_class_type%", '([^/]+)', "classes_class_type=");
        $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('classes_class_type', $class_type_structure, false);
        }

add_action( 'init', 'create_class_type_taxonomies', 0 );
```